# Uniform bound on solutions to a family of Elliptic PDEs.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am given a family of problems :

$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u_\varepsilon = f+\beta_\varepsilon(u_\varepsilon)& \text{in } D \\[2pt]
u_\varepsilon=w & \text{on } \partial D
\end{cases}
$$

with $u_\varepsilon$ solving the above equation in $D\subset \mathbb R^N$ open and bounded.

We have $\beta_\varepsilon(s)=\frac 1 \varepsilon \beta \left( \frac s \varepsilon \right)$.

$\beta$ is a smooth function such that 
$$
\begin{cases}
 \beta \geq 0 \\[2pt]
  \beta \equiv 0 & \text{in } (0,1)^c \\[2pt]
 \int_{\mathbb R}\beta=1
\end{cases}
$$

And $f\in L^\infty(D)$, $0<a<f<A<\infty$, for some $a,A>0$. I wish to prove $u_\varepsilon$ is uniformly bounded in $D$ with bound independent of $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.

The bound may depend on the boundary condition.

Comment: Is $\beta$ monotonically decreasing? That would help alot.

Comment: No, $\beta$ is like a bump function. Supported on set $(0,1)$ and as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, support of bump of $\beta_{\epsilon}$ shrinks and $\beta_{\epsilon}$ rised to that $\int_{\mathbb R}\beta _{\epsilon}$ remains $=1$

Comment: I plan on working this out later today if no one else has, but note that $\beta_{\epsilon}$ is what is called a mollifier. Mollifiers are meant to "smooth" out the function. You have a function $u_{\epsilon}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f*\beta_{\epsilon} dx$ which smooths out $u$, even if $u$ is discontinuous. I think the solution will be a clever manipulation of mollifiers, and some other regularity results for elliptic PDEs.

Comment: No, the functions $u_{\epsilon}$ are solutions corresponding to the given equation. Actually the PDE is E-L equation of a mollified version for the energy $\int_{D}\frac{1}{2}|u|^2-fu+\chi_{u>0}$ where $\chi_{u>0}$ is mollified to a smoother alternative $\int_{0}^{u_{\epsilon}}\beta_{\epsilon}(s)\,ds$. The replacement for characteristic rises from 0 to 1 in $(0,\epsilon)$

Comment: I think I found the answer, thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, though the singular term made it look complicated.
1. In the set say $\Omega_{\epsilon}=\{u_\epsilon >\epsilon\}$, we have 
$$
-\Delta u_{\epsilon}=f\;\;\text {in $\Omega_{\epsilon}$}
$$
From Theorem 8.16 in "Gilbarg,Trudinger-Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order-Springer (2001)" 
The solution $u_{\epsilon}$ is bounded as long as the boundary term $w$ is bounded,

In rest of the region, $\{u_{\epsilon}\leq \epsilon\}$, we already have a bound.